# How do I update a property (like the color) of an HTML element from Typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have the following in the HTML portion of my page

```
<ion-row padding>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="addressSearchfield" name="addressSearch'></ion-input>
</ion-row>
```

and I'd like to change the color of the ion-input in the TS potion of the page.

I can get the value stored in it with code like this

```
addressSearchfield: string;
//...
console.log (this.addressSearchfield);
```

I had assume I can reference the element and its properties it something like this:

```
addressrow: any;
// ...
this.addressSearch.color = '#FFFFFF';
```

but I get the error `Cannot set property 'color' of undefined`

How should I be doing this?

Comment: The same way you do it from JavaScript... `document.querySelector('[name="addressSearch"]').style.color = '#FFFFFF';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more "Ionic way" to do this would be by using **CSS properties**. Just like you can see in **[the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#css-custom-properties)**, the `ion-input` has a CSS property that sets the `color`:

```
CSS Custom Properties

Name    | Description
--------|------------------------
...
--color | Color of the input text
...
```

So you could define a new CSS property in the `variables.scss` file, like this:

```
:root {

  // ...

  --input-custom-color: blue; // default color for the input

}
```

Then in your page, set the color of the input to use that CSS property:

```
// my-page.page.scss

[name="addressSearch"] {
  --color: var(--input-custom-color);
}
```

That would just use the default color. So now the following code is to change that color (or actually, the value of the CSS property) from the component:

```
// Angular
import { Component, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// Ionic
import { DomController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: "app-my-page",
  templateUrl: "my-page.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["my-page.page.scss"]
})
export class MyPage {

  constructor(
    private domCtrl: DomController,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document
  ) {}

  public changeColor(aColor: string): void {

    // Tell Ionic we're going to write in the DOM
    this.domCtrl.write(() => {

      // Update the value of the CSS property
      this.document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--input-custom-color', aColor);
    });
  }
}
```

Now you can do something like `this.changeColor('green');` and the color of the input will we updated in the view :)

The biggest advantage of doing this is that you can change all your inputs by just updating that CSS property (even inputs located in any other page from your app) instead of accessing directly to each DOM element to update its styles.

Please notice that doing the same will work for any styles - it doesn't matter if Ionic uses a CSS property like `--color` or if it's just the `color` CSS attribute (like this: `color: var(--input-custom-color);`)

Answer (score 0):

OK, Heretic Monkey's answer technically works,

```
document.querySelector('[name="addressSearch"]').style.color = '#FFFFFF';
```

but it gives me a red-squiggle in my editor on the style element

However, with a bit of experimentation based on that:

```
addressSearch: HTMLElement;
// ...
this.addressSearch= document.querySelector('[name="addressSearch"]');
this.addressSearch.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
```

gives the same effect, with a happier editor.

Comment: `ion-input` uses the `--color` CSS property behind the scenes so there's a more "ionic way" to do this... I can add an answer if you think it may help...

Comment: sebaferreras, by all means - make it more complete